# How can I download OpenFrameworks documentation

Tags: openframeworks

Is it possible to download the OpenFrameworks documentation to view locally?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked in openFrameworks for several months and I personally found the best documentation of openFrameworks is the source code itself.

I did not crunch the numbers, but far too many methods are without any explanation in the *documentation*. By studying the code itself, you'll more likely to find the answers you're looking for.

To view the source locally, just clone the GitHub repository or pull a zip-file from https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

You can download the OF documentation in zip format from the OF forum > http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/openframeworks-offline-documentation-for-download/13898

Thanks to Lewis Lepton / smokingbunny.net

### OLD ANSWER:

You could have a look at the [ofSite on github](https://github.com/openframeworks/ofSite). Not sure though if it'll come in formats that work on your harddrive.

Comment: can you provide me a way to make the documentation on the website in a pdf format so that i can print it ?